# How do I find which .so files are being referenced by GCC

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries

When I compile, I want to know exactly which shared libraries my executable relies on.  Is there a way to get gcc to tell me the full path of the libraries it referenced during the linking process?

To be more specific, I am cross compiling for embedded linux.  There are several versions of libstdc++.so in my file system.  I need to make sure the executable references the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You'll may want to look at the output of `gcc -v ...` for the load (it is really the linker, `ld(1)`, who figures that out from the paths given as arguments, or perhaps environment variables like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). Or run `ldd(1)` on the final executable.